# How to get selected li value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array list as shown below

var items = ['Iphones', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'] which I append to a li as below.

**HTML & JS**

```
<div id="host">
<div class="data_box"></div>
</div>

     $.ajax({
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (results) { 
             $('.data_box').html('<li class="li_of_phones">'+results.toString().split(',').join('<br/>')+'</li>').slideDown();
             },});


     <script>
        $('#host').on('click', '.li_of_phones', function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
        });
      </script>
```

When I try to get the selected li when user clicks, it returns the array i.e `Iphones,Samsung,Huawei` instead of the selected phone (may be iphones)

Why am I not getting the selected phone when user clicks on the `li` but then it returns the all phones in the array to user?

Comment: You should try by adding  event listener on li instead of div#host

Comment: @AkshayBande, How would that work?

Comment: um, you only have on li.... Some odd reason you are using br inside of an li.

Comment: @RoboPHP I have posted my answer by creating small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you receive the results from the ajax call as a comma separated string and then set it in a single `<li>` element with the `li_of_phones` class.

You could loop the splitted response in a foreach and create different li elements for each result.

```js
const results = 'Iphones, Samsung, Huawei';

let phonesList = '';
results.split(',').forEach(phone => {
   phonesList += '<li class="li_of_phones">' + phone.trim() + '</li>';
});
$('.data_box').html(phonesList).slideDown();

$('#host').on('click', '.li_of_phones', function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5.5em !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="host">
    <ul class="data_box"></ul>
</div>
```

You might have to change some css styles of the resulting list items.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event on li. I have created a small example.

```js
$('li').click(function(e) {

  console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```